# How to create external table in CnosDB from CSV with a time column using nanosecond timestamps?

Tags: cnosdb

I'm testing searching time series data in some CSV files using cnosdb,  but it looks like cnosdb could not parse nanosecond timestamps as `timestamp` type.

I have a simple CSV file:

> `D:\tmp\csv\simple_data.csv`

```
time,ta,tb,tc,fa,fb,fc
1688101200000000,a1,b1,c1,1,10,100
1688101230000000,a1,b1,c1,1,10,100
1688101300000000,a1,b1,c1,1,10,100
```

I use this statement to create external table:

> [Doc: Create External Table](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/sql.html#create-external-table)

```bash
public ❯ create external table simple_data_ext (
    time timestamp,
    ta string,
    tb string,
    tc string,
    fa double,
    fb double,
    fc double
) stored as csv with header row location 'D:\tmp\csv\simple_data.csv';
Query took 0.322 seconds.
public ❯ select * from simple_data_ext;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010002","error_message":"Arrow: Parser error: Error parsing column 0 at line 2: Parser error: Error parsing timestamp from '1688101230000000': error parsing date"}
```

But if I edited the CSV file to change time column to RFC-3339 format:

```
time,ta,tb,tc,fa,fb,fc
2023-06-30T13:00:00,a1,b1,c1,1,10,100
2023-06-30T13:00:30,a1,b1,c1,1,10,100
2023-06-30T13:01:00,a1,b1,c1,1,10,100
```

Then I got expected result:

```bash
public ❯ select * from simple_data_ext;
+---------------------+----+----+----+-----+------+-------+
| time                | ta | tb | tc | fa  | fb   | fc    |
+---------------------+----+----+----+-----+------+-------+
| 2023-06-30T13:00:00 | a1 | b1 | c1 | 1.0 | 10.0 | 100.0 |
| 2023-06-30T13:00:30 | a1 | b1 | c1 | 1.0 | 10.0 | 100.0 |
| 2023-06-30T13:01:00 | a1 | b1 | c1 | 1.0 | 10.0 | 100.0 |
+---------------------+----+----+----+-----+------+-------+
Query took 0.004 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

This document shows that data type `timestamp` only supports RFC-3339 format: [Doc: Database](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/reference/sql.html#database)

Answer (score 0):

The new version should have fixed this problem. The version I used is:cnosdb 2.3.2, revision 1e64abaf54312ec7c75c6d7c925064635b2280a3.
the step as follow:

```sql
cnosdb-cli 
CnosDB CLI v2.3.0
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "root", password: None, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, precision: None }
public ❯ create external table test stored as csv WITH HEADER ROW
LOCATION '/home/bca/script/test.csv';
Query took 0.014 seconds.
public ❯ \d
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| readings   |
| test       |
+------------+
Query took 0.005 seconds.
public ❯ select * from test;
+---------------------+----------------+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
| time                | device_version | driver | fleet | model  | name    | latitude | longitude | elevation | velocity | heading | grade | fuel_consumption | load_capacity | fuel_capacity | nominal_fuel_consumption |
+---------------------+----------------+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
| 1420070400000000000 | v2_3           | Trish  | South | H_2    | truck_0 | 52.31854 | 4.72037   | 124       | 0        | 221     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v1_5           | Albert | South | F_150  | truck_1 | 72.45258 | 68.83761  | 255       | 0        | 181     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v1_5           | Derek  | North | F_150  | truck_2 | 24.5208  | 28.09377  | 428       | 0        | 304     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v2_0           | Albert | East  | F_150  | truck_3 | 18.11037 | 98.65573  | 387       | 0        | 192     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v1_5           | Andy   | West  | G_2000 | truck_4 | 81.93919 | 56.12266  | 236       | 0        | 335     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v2_0           | Seth   | East  | F_150  | truck_5 | 5.00552  | 114.50557 | 89        | 0        | 187     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v1_0           | Trish  | East  | G_2000 | truck_6 | 41.59689 | 57.90174  | 395       | 0        | 150     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v1_0           | Seth   | South | G_2000 | truck_8 | 21.89157 | 44.58919  | 411       | 0        | 232     | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
| 1420070400000000000 | v2_3           | Andy   | South | H_2    | truck_9 | 15.67271 | 112.4023  | 402       | 0        | 75      | 0     | 25               | 0             | 0             | 0                        |
+---------------------+----------------+--------+-------+--------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+-------+------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------+
Query took 0.007 seconds.
public ❯ \q
```

the data as follow:

```
time,device_version,driver,fleet,model,name,latitude,longitude,elevation,velocity,heading,grade,fuel_consumption,load_capacity,fuel_capacity,nominal_fuel_consumption
1420070400000000000,v2_3,Trish,South,H_2,truck_0,52.31854,4.72037,124,0,221,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v1_5,Albert,South,F_150,truck_1,72.45258,68.83761,255,0,181,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v1_5,Derek,North,F_150,truck_2,24.5208,28.09377,428,0,304,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v2_0,Albert,East,F_150,truck_3,18.11037,98.65573,387,0,192,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v1_5,Andy,West,G_2000,truck_4,81.93919,56.12266,236,0,335,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v2_0,Seth,East,F_150,truck_5,5.00552,114.50557,89,0,187,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v1_0,Trish,East,G_2000,truck_6,41.59689,57.90174,395,0,150,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v1_0,Seth,South,G_2000,truck_8,21.89157,44.58919,411,0,232,0,25,0,0,0
1420070400000000000,v2_3,Andy,South,H_2,truck_9,15.67271,112.4023,402,0,75,0,25,0,0,0
```